# jquery Select value attributes and apply each value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to select all stroke attributes and return their value for each corresponding element. Only, I used each (), map () I can not do it.

I have a function

```
function (el, i) {
  i = $('.line-code path').attr('stroke');
  return i
}
```

With this one, I select only applies the first color to all elements and that is not what I want.

Here are the elements that I want to select (there are 33 in total, but I put only 3)

```
<path d="M720.5 521.5H785" stroke="#4990E2"/>
<path d="M757.5 541.5H787" stroke="#000"/>
<path d="M808.5 541.5H911" stroke="#FFF"/>
```

And then, with my function, I want to apply the color retrieved to each corresponding element.

PS: Higher in my script, I define all colors to "none", thanks to this function, I want to reapply the original colors.

Thank you very much !

Comment: What _are_ those corresponding elements? Can you provide some samples?

Answer (score 1):

you can  use [array#map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to get all the values.

```js
var arr=[];
//iterating the path
$('path').map(function(v){
//push values of stroke into the array
arr.push($(this).attr('stroke'));
});
$('p').map(function(i,v){
//for each p assign a color from the array
$(this).css("color",arr[i])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<path d="M720.5 521.5H785" stroke="#4990E2"/>
<path d="M757.5 541.5H787" stroke="#000"/>
<path d="M808.5 541.5H911" stroke="#eee"/>
<p>element 1</p>
<p>element 2</p>
<p>element 3</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `.map()` plain JavaScript. Details commented in Snippet:

**SNIPPET**

```js
// Collect all <path>s in a NodeList
var paths = document.querySelectorAll('path');

/* Use map() method to convert NodeList
|| into an array and to use getAttribute()
|| method on each of the <path>'s stroke
|| and finally return an array of stroke
|| values (ie colors)
*/
var colors = Array.prototype.map.call(paths, function(obj) {
  var shade = obj.getAttribute('stroke');
  return shade;
});

console.log(colors);
```

```html
<svg height="400" width="400">
<path d="M 5.5 21.5 l 85 200" stroke="#4990E2" stroke-width='5'/>
<path d="M 7.5 21.5 l 187 170" stroke="#000" stroke-width='15'/>
<path d="M 8.5 41.5 l 300 10" stroke="#F00" stroke-width='5'/>
</svg>
```